# Question to mapKeyPath

Tags: ios, restkit

I am following the Restkit Tutorial on https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/master/Docs/Object%20Mapping.md and this is pretty good because RestKit is a really cool framework - I think.

There is just one point I don't get. In the documentation is a line with "article" but I cannot see where article is declared and where it comes from.

```
// Define the relationship mapping [article mapKeyPath:@"author"
toRelationship:@"author" withMapping:authorMapping];
```

Can someone give some light into the darkness?

Is this the right area on how to handle 1:n relationships that are nested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line should be:

```
[articleMapping mapKeyPath:@"author" toRelationship:@"author" withMapping:authorMapping];
```

The updated article on the [wiki](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping) has the correction.